# Clique do mouse em <TR> da tabela não acionar o ultimo <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Abaixo tenho uma linha  de uma tabela. Esta linha pode ser marcada ao clicar em qualquer local dela com o mouse acionando um evento click.

Porém, específicamente no  do botão, não desejo que seja acionado o evento javascript. Pois da maneira que está nunca aciona o submit do botão, apenas chama o evento javascript. É possível?

```
<tr role="row" class="bg-green disabled color-palette">
    <form method="POST" action="index.php"></form>
        <td class="sorting_1">26-OCT-17</td>
        <td>02:00</td>
        <td>Quinta-feira</td>
        <td>Sala 02 Bloco Cirurgico</td>
        <td class="text-center botao-td">
            <button type="submit" class="btn bg-navy btn-flat loading" id="botao-formulario"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> </button>
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

-- Javascript:

```
 $("#grade-horario tr").click(function(){
     Ações.....
 }
```

Comment: Não seria mais facil ativar uma função chamada por um id e dar esse id para cada uma das 'td's que vão poder ter o click? Ou então compare o valor do $(this) com o valor da td que vc não quer que tenha o click e então só continue o código se o $(this) não for igual a ela

Comment: Essa comparação que você disse com o cógigo do TD, como eu poderia fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Altere seu código js, use os seletores [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) e [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), faz assim:

```
$("#grade-horario tr td:not(:nth-child(5))").click(function(){
    //ações
}
```

Comment: Desconfigurou tudo. Nâo teria como fazer algum IF? tipo se for clicada na 5ª coluna (td) não faz nada, senão faz.